# Doop: Gradle build failed with an exception. Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to setup doop. After running the command ./doop, I get the following error:

- What went wrong:
  Error resolving plugin [id: 'net.researchgate.release', version: '2.6.0']

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
  >   Could not determine artifacts for net.researchgate.release:net.researchgate.release.gradle.plugin:2.6.0
  >   Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/researchgate/release/net.researchgate.release.gradle.plugin/2.6.0/net.researchgate.release.gradle.plugin-2.6.0.jar'.
  >   Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/researchgate/release/net.researchgate.release.gradle.plugin/2.6.0/net.researchgate.release.gradle.plugin-2.6.0.jar'.
  >   Remote host closed connection during handshake

Can anyone help me understand and resolve the error better?

Comment: First of all, did a retry fix it? There have been some issues with Artifactory recently and it is what hosts files behind plugins.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was java version issue.
It worked fine with java 1.8. I was using java 1.7